# Perforce external diff in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, perforce, p4merge, p4eclipse

I am using the [P4Eclipse](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/eclipse_plugin) plugin for seamless integration with Perforce. I feel comfortable doing most of the P4 things with this plugin, except file diffing.

By `Team - Diff File(s) against Depot` in the right-click context menu, an internal "Depot Diff" view opens to provide a simple diff feature - I am not satisfied with this menu option, though. I prefer the P4Merge external diff tool, which is the default diff tool of the Perforce Visual Client (P4V).

In Preferences of Eclipse, I found a location to fill in the path of P4Merge. It's `Team - Perforce - External Tools`. But I think this setting is only for file resolving.

Is there a way to directly call P4Merge for file diffing in Eclipse?

Comment: were you able to find a proper solution to your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up an external tool to run P4Merge (I think).

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-exttools.htm

Comment: How can I let P4Merge know where to get the remote file to diff with?

Comment: Although this is not a complete solution for my original question, I think it is really a good point to start with. As the first and only answer I will accept it and give the bounty. Thanks!

Comment: @Hailei did you set the p4 merge as external tool.. I have no idea how to set external tools. Kindly help me with some steps or doc to set it up.