# How do I view diffs made to a program file in the Eclipse editor using Perforce's plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, perforce

I want a visual indicator of changes made to my program file in the Eclipse editor. For example, a new line added to the file should appear as green (or any other color) in the editor. How do I make this happen? I am using eclipse Juno and I have Perforce plugin installed.

Comment: Possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533401/perforce-external-diff-in-eclipse

Comment: Have you tried "Quick Diff"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the Perforce perspective, then viewing the diffs in Eclipse's "P4 Pending Changelists" tab via "Compare with Source Revision"? It's not color-coded, but is an obvious visual indication.